# Upgrade symfony version 3.4 to 6.2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I hope you all are doing good but I'm not due to this hectic issue which I'm trying to fix from 2 days. Any help regarding my query will be appreciated.

I'm getting this issue after upgrading my symfony version from 3.4 to 6.2. You can check attach screenshot.

I just change my "symfony/symfony": "3.4.x-dev" to "symfony/symfony": "6.2.x-dev" and update relevant package version and everything was going good but at the end I got this issue :

[Please click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UUWq.png)

Please let me know what I am missing ?

Comment: What is "this issue"? Please add it to your question in text form. Also, is there any good reason to use development versions of Symfony? Why not use a stable one?

Comment: Also, it could be way simpler to take this upgrade step by step. Most probably you need to change a lot of configuration, and a lot of code when updating from 3.4 to 6.2 directly.

Comment: You can't just jump 3 major versions up and expect everything to work exactly the same. It seems some of the libraries in your composer.json are incompatible with Symfony 6.2. You'll have to update/replace each of them, and change your code accordingly.

Comment: You can automate your migration using https://getrector.com. Find an example here https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony6-upgrade/rector. Before running composer update, you can also delete the vendor folder and the symfony.lock file to avoid the error you mention

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

- update versions 1 by 1
  3.4, 4.4, 5.4, 6.2
- install a new 6.2 and copy-paste your 3.2 src in it, then redo all the configuration by hand.

gl.

Answer (score 0):

Swiftmailer-bundle is not supported beyond Symfony 5.0 - you will have to switch to symfony/mailer and refactor your code appropriately. Similarly, you can now either have symfony/symfony or symfony/config, but not both.

You'll also want to switch to Flex around Symfony4 and refactor your project structure.

All in all, you probably want to paste your 3.2 into a new 6.2 project and update all of your controllers and services auto-wired dependency injection. It's weeks worth of work.